# What is the return type for JPA query method when query result is not a class?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have this query in JPA:

```
@Query("SELECT programId,COUNT(id) FROM Therapy GROUP BY programId ORDER BY COUNT(id) DESC")
List<Object> top10ProgramsOfTherapies();
```

It works great, but it returns a list of Objects, and I can not get the data out of it. What return type should I use to read the result data?

Comment: each Object will actually be an Object[]

Comment: @ScaryWombat You are right, but it's rather *each item is an `Object[]`*., beacause *each `Object` will actually be an `Object[]`* is a little bit confusing, isn't it!? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query will return a list of objects array: `Object[]` so you need to change your code like this:

```
@Query("SELECT programId,COUNT(id) FROM Therapy GROUP BY programId ORDER BY COUNT(id) DESC")
List<Object[]> top10ProgramsOfTherapies();
```

And for each `item` in the list : `item[0]` will hold the `programID` value and `item[1]` will hold the `COUNT(id)` value, and you should cast them to their respective types as they will be just `object`s.

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly. The method indeed returns a list of object arrays, but the objects in the array are actually Longs.

Comment: @MarkBuikema Yes they are `Long`s but it's safer to use the cast, I think.

Answer (score 4):

You can also create a DTO class, for example, `TherapyDto` which will have a constructor with 2 parameters and use it this way:

```
@Query("SELECT new com.my.TherapyDto(programId,COUNT(id)) FROM Therapy GROUP BY programId ORDER BY COUNT(id) DESC")
List<TherapyDto> top10ProgramsOfTherapies();
```